# copy file in Java using FileStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I want to copy a file in Java using FileStream.
This is my code.

```
FileInputStream infile = new FileInputStream("in");
FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream("out");

byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while(infile.read(b, 0, 1024) > 0){
    outfile.write(b);
}

infile.close();
outfile.close();
```

I use vim to view my file.
Input file "in"

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
```

Output file "output"

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...
```

There are many extra '^@' in the output file.
Size of input file is 39 Bytes.
And size of output file is 1KB.
Why that there are many extra char in the output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `infile.read`, the return value tells you how many items you are getting back. When you call `outfile.write`, you tell it that the buffer is filled, because you did not store the number of bytes that you got back from the `read` call.

To fix this problem store the number of bytes, then pass the proper number to `write`:

```
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len = infile.read(b, 0, 1024)) > 0){
    outfile.write(b, 0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to copy `1024` bytes from the file to another. That will not work well. Try to read by the size of the file.

```
FileInputStream infile = new FileInputStream("in");
FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream("out");

byte[] b = new byte[infile.getChannel().size()];
while(infile.read(b, 0, infile.getChannel().size()) > 0){
    outfile.write(b);
}

infile.close();
outfile.close();
```

Comment: what will happen if the size of the file is too big?

Comment: It would probably give you `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception. In that case you can still increase memory though...

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array b[] is 1KB. The extra character '@' is appended to show that the file still has space that is left unutilized. Technically you are copying a file in a byte array and writing the but array in the output file. That is why this problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to copy file is a call of the single method
1. before Java 7 - from [Google Guava](http://google.github.io/guava) library
[com.google.common.io.Files#copy(File from,
        File to)](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#copy(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))
2. in Java 7 & 8
[java.nio.file.Files#copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)